# Parallel invocation of elements of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` method called `Batch` that works like

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 8, 10, -4, 3 }; 
var batches = list.Batch(2); 
foreach(var batch in batches)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", batch));
```

-->

```
1,2
4,8
10,-4
3
```

The problem I've having is that I'm to optimize something like

```
foreach(var batch in batches)
    ExecuteBatch(batch);
```

by

```
Task[] tasks = batches.Select(batch => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteBatch(batch))).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

or

```
Action[] executions = batches.Select(batch => new Action(() => ExecuteBatch(batch))).ToArray();
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
Parallel.Invoke(options, executions);
```

(because `ExecuteBatch` is a long-running operation involving IO)

then I notice that each `batch` gets screwed up, is only 1 element which is `default(int)`. Any idea what's happening or how to fix it?

Batch:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    for(var mover = source.GetEnumerator(); ;)
    {
        if(!mover.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        yield return LimitMoves(mover, size);
    }
}
private static IEnumerable<T> LimitMoves<T>(IEnumerator<T> mover, int limit)
{
    do yield return mover.Current;
    while(--limit > 0 && mover.MoveNext());
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue? Are you saying the `Batch` method is not working? In that case, it'd be a good idea to show us the implementation of it

Comment: @Rob Added the implementation

Comment: Your problem is that `Batch` is exhausting the enumerator (it's in a for loop, and continually calling `MoveNext()` before `LimitMoves` ever gets a chance. The actual bug is caused by materializing the collection with `ToArray()`, nothing to do with parallelism. If you change your original code to `var batches = list.Batch(2).ToList();`, you'll see the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments, your actual issue is your implementation of `Batch`.

This code:

```
for(var mover = source.GetEnumerator(); ;)
{
    if(!mover.MoveNext())
        yield break;
    yield return LimitMoves(mover, size);
}
```

When `Batch` is materialized, this code is going to continually call `MoveNext()` until the enumerable is exhausted. `LimitMoves()` uses the same iterator, and is *lazily* invoked. Since `Batch` exhausts the enumerable, `LimitMoves()` will never emit an item. (Actually, it will only emit `default(T)` since it always returns `mover.Current`, which will be `default(T)` once the enumerable is finished).

Here's an implementation of `Batch` which will work when materialized (and thus when in parallel).

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    var mover = source.GetEnumerator();
    var currentSet = new List<T>();
    while (mover.MoveNext())
    {
        currentSet.Add(mover.Current);
        if (currentSet.Count >= size)
        {   
            yield return currentSet;
            currentSet = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (currentSet.Count > 0)
        yield return currentSet;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) - which comes with a `Batch` implementation. You can see their implementation [here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)